# Xamarin XAML ListView - How to select programmatically

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing a windows mobile application with Xamarin, but don't seem to be able to programmatically set the selected ListView item.

I have tried the following ListViews methods and still nothing

```
SelectedItem
ScrollTo()
Focus()
```

I have also googled it and can't seem anything to say how to do this. 
How do I do this?

Comment: You should post the code you are trying that is not producing the result you want.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works fine in my sample app:

```
public partial class ItemsPage : ContentPage
{
    public ItemsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Vm = new ItemsViewModel();
        BindingContext = Vm;
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        ListviewItems.SelectedItem = Vm.Items[1];
    }

    public ItemsViewModel Vm { get; private set; }
```

In my sample app, `ItemsViewModel.Items` is a `List<string>`.

The second item in the list is set selected after this line of code runs in `OnAppearing`.

Answer (score 1):

setting the `SelectedItem` property is the "correct" way to do it.  What specifically is not happening that you think you happen when it is set?

Answer (score 1):

I used a method but it may not be the most effective one. You can set your change to the list which was created by your model type and then you should reload the list view.

```
subjects[i].something=false;//set something

yourListView.ItemSource=null;
yourListView.ItemSource=subjects;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to scroll to the specific location, 
I am using

`listChat.SetSelection(currentIndex);`

in one of my chat application and it works fine.

if you are looking for the solution to scroll to desired position, even I have searched for the solution on internet, nothing helped. finally this one was my work around to make it work.