# No way to get ListView to show initial selected item

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

There seems to be no way to get an initial selection to be show in a Xamarin Forms ListView.  I see that this question has been asked a few times, however in each case there is either no relevant answer or the unanswered question is too complicated to be analyzed properly or the question is answered but the answer does not work.  So I thought I would pose a simplified version of this question in the hope that someone can show me a workaround.  A workaround is all that can be done because it has become clear to be that the SelectedItem cannot be bound and it cannot be set from code.  Here are the SO question I have examined...

[:Why can't I set the SelectedItem property of Xamarin.Forms.ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666776/why-cant-i-set-the-selecteditem-property-of-xamarin-forms-listview)

[Xamarin Forms ListView SelectedItem Binding Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45364080/xamarin-forms-listview-selecteditem-binding-issue/45378375)

[Xamarin.Forms ListView set SelectedItem by Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32870279/xamarin-forms-listview-set-selecteditem-by-code)

[Xamarin XAML ListView - How to select programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36476556/xamarin-xaml-listview-how-to-select-programatically)

Here is the XAML...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamarinFormsBench"
         x:Class="XamarinFormsBench.ListViewPage1">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:ViewModel1/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ListView x:Name="MyListView" Margin="0,20,0,0"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" 
          BindingContextChanged="MyListView_BindingContextChanged">
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is the code...

```
public class Item
{
    public Item(string name, string description)
    {
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
    }
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name + " = " + Description;
    }
}

public class ViewModel1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public ViewModel1()
    {

        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>
        {
            new Item("Item 1","First item"),
            new Item("Item 2","Second item"),
            new Item("Item 3","Third item"),
            new Item("Item 4","Fourth item"),
            new Item("Item 5","Fifth item")
        };
        _selectedItem = Items[2];
    }
    Item _selectedItem;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public Item SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem));
        }
    }
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ListViewPage1 : ContentPage
{
    public ListViewPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public ViewModel1 ViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return BindingContext as ViewModel1;
        }
    }

    private void MyListView_BindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //         MyListView.SelectedItem = ViewModel.SelectedItem;
    }
}
```

My expectation is that a list of 5 items appears and the 3rd item will be highlighted.  What happens is that 5 items appears but no item is highlighted.  The binding clearly works because the selected item is updated each time I click on an item.

Now if I remove the binding and try to set the selected item in code by uncommenting the line near the end, that does not work either.

So I am out of ideas.  I've been looking at simulating a mouse click but this is really a kluge beyond where I am willing to go.

I have run this code on UWP and Android.  Haven't tried iOS.

Comment: try  change `_selectedItem = Items[2];` to `SelectedItem = Items[2];`. when you edit the private field directly, you lose the propertyChange event notificaion.

Comment: Tried that.  No change particularly because that code is in the view model constructor and so the property changed event is null.  I also added the code to the binding context changed event handler.  I also set SelectedItem to null and then back to Items[2] still without effect.  I have tried everything.

Comment: ok. try replace the ListView with another ItemsControl.

Comment: ItemsView you mean?  Among collection views there is only Picker and TableView in addition to ListView.  Neither one of these are replacements for ListView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it turns out this is only a problem on UWP.  The workaround to get this working for UWP is as follows in ListViewPage1 :

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        // *STANDARD MASSIVE KLUGE* Needed to get initial selection to show.
        Item m = MyListView.SelectedItem as Item;
        MyListView.SelectedItem = null;
        MyListView.SelectedItem = m;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I just created a quick test solution and this all worked for me on both iOS and Android.

The difference is I was using FreshMvvm to bind the View and ViewModel and PropertyChanged.Fody to automate the notification.

This suggests it is your binding or propertychanged that is causing the issue.

Here is the viewmodel

```
[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
public class MainPageModel : FreshBasePageModel
{
    public MainPageModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>
        {
            new Item("Item 1","First item"),
            new Item("Item 2","Second item"),
            new Item("Item 3","Third item"),
            new Item("Item 4","Fourth item"),
            new Item("Item 5","Fifth item")
        };

        SelectedItem = Items[2];
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public Item SelectedItem { get; set; }
}
```

And the view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ScratchPad.Pages.MainPage"
             Title="List Test">

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
    </ListView>

</ContentPage>
```

And the App.xaml.cs just for good measure

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var page = FreshPageModelResolver.ResolvePageModel<MainPageModel>();
        var nav = new FreshNavigationContainer(page);
        MainPage = nav;

    }

    ...
}
```

[image]

EDIT "Pure" Xamarin Forms Code

Here is the View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:selectedItemTest="clr-namespace:SelectedItemTest;assembly=SelectedItemTest"
             x:Class="SelectedItemTest.MainPage"
             Title="List Test">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <selectedItemTest:MainPageModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
    </ListView>

</ContentPage>
```

And the view model

```
public class MainPageModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public MainPageModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>
        {
            new Item("Item 1","First item"),
            new Item("Item 2","Second item"),
            new Item("Item 3","Third item"),
            new Item("Item 4","Fourth item"),
            new Item("Item 5","Fifth item")
        };

        SelectedItem = Items[2];
    }

    private Item _selectedItem;
    public Item SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steve.  Not interested in 3rd party solution at the moment.  I want to get the basic machinery working.  Can you update your answer with the code?  If it is too big to fit in the answer...well that says something doesn't it?

Comment: Added code. FreshMvvm is very lightweight. Just glue for joining view and viewmodel, a small IOC container and some helper methods. PropertyChanged.Fody helps remove all the property changed boilerplate. Just an attribute at the top.

Comment: Looks very interesting.  I'll look into it.  I still want to see a solution using pure Xamarin Forms.  Unless I am mistaken this is a serious bug that needs to be fixed.  In fact given that the same question has been asked over a span of years suggests that this is another Xamarin perma-bug of which there are many.  The ListViewArray example in Chapter 19 of Charles Petzold's book binds the SelectedItem to a BoxView control and this works!  So this is one idea for a standard massive kluge: bind the ListView selected item to a Label and then bind the Label to something else.

Comment: Just added code for a solution using Pure Xamarin Forms. Works.

Comment: What version of Xamarin Forms are you using?

Comment: The latest 2.5.0.91635.  But also 2.4.0.282 and a lot of versions.  Will try your "pure" solution tomorrow when I have a moment.  Thanks.

Comment: Right.  So as it turns out your pure answer works on Android but not UWP.  Also my original problem works now on Android but not UWP.  So this appears to be some bug in UWP Xamarin,  I tested the orignal problem on both UWP and Android, so I am not sure what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you trying something like this:

```
            List<TodoItem> items = await todoTable.OrderByDescending(todoItem => todoItem.CreatedAt).ToListAsync();


            listView.Items.Clear();
            if (items.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    string row = "";
                    row += $"Name: {item.Text}" + $" created at {item.CreatedAt.ToLocalTime()}";
                    listView.Items.Add(row);
                }
                int selectedItem = 2;
                if(items.Count > selectedItem)
                    listView.SelectedIndex = selectedItem;
            }
```

My code gets data from a Azure table but it should work the same way for any type of data. You can load the index from any source or have it hard-coded.

Review this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListView

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed as of this writing on the Xamarin.Forms master branch. See [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1356) for reference.